# is not a legal prefix for a constructor when creating a nested class

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to create an instance of a Java nested class but when compile I see `is not a legal prefix for a constructor`.

I have a Java library with classes A1 and A2 defined like this

```java
public class A1 {
  public class A2 {
    public A2() {...}
  }
  public A2 getA2() {
    return new A2();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to extend this class in Scala and doing something like this

```scala
class B(...) extends A1(...) {
  override def getA2() = {
    new A1#A2()
  }
}
```

When I compile I get this error

```
 A1 is not a legal prefix for a constructor
[error]     new A1#A2()
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (connector/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 21, 2020 11:34:44 PM
[IJ]>
```

This seems to be a known compiler issue (see [github issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4859)), the workaround won't work here as I cannot change the library code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an instance of that issue. Trying to say `new A1#A2` is like trying to say `def mk[T]() = new T`. You're missing out on essential information. *For which* `A1` do you want to make an `A2`? In your code, you just want to instantiate `new this.A2()`. You can omit the `this`, as usual: `new A2()`

```
class B(...) extends A1(...) {
  override def getA2() = new A2()
}
```

The reason `new A1#A2()` fails is because each `A1` has its own `A2`. For

```
val a: A1 = ???
val b: A1 = ???
```

`a.A2` and `b.A2` are different types. `A1#A2` is not a name for "the 'underlying' `A2` class that all `A1`s share," because in Scala there is no such thing (the fact that Java's `A1.A2` does work like that might be seen as a leaky abstraction on Java's part). `A1#A2` is actually more like a wildcard type: `A2` *for some* `A1`. Just like you can't say `new Array[_](5)` (what element type do you want?), you can't say `new A1#A2()` (which `A1` do you want?).

Comment: I had assumed that `A1#A2` is just the base type of all `A2` types inside instances of `A1`, but there is no class with this type so no instances can be created.